# Google Compute Engine: Unable to attach GPU to instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Here is what I am trying to do:
I configured an instance on Google Compute Engine to use NVIDIA K80 GPU. You can see the hardware specs below.

[image]

First time I also opened "Quotas" page and requested a GPU for `europe-west1` zone. I had "0/0". Then after some bureaucracy proceedings with Google support they gave me one GPU. So now it looks like this:

[image]

Now,the problem is, when I launch the instance, I am always getting:

> The zone 'projects/eyeframeserver/zones/europe-west1-b' does not have
>   enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different
>   zone, or try again later.

This is already second day in row that I am trying it,and nothing changes. The dudes from Google to whom I submit quota requests say it is not their problem. And Google groups are silent.

I also tried to re-create instance from scratch,using different hardware params. it only start-ups ok,if the GPU is not attached.

Comment: Please I would like to take a further look to this issue. I work for Google Cloud Support. Could you please open a private issue, an add your project number: issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164 Please post a new comment with the issue ID and once we found the solution I will post it here so anyone can have the answer.

Comment: @PolArroyo  sure,no problem.

Comment: @PolArroyo  submitted  the issue .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the CPU platform you selected was either Automatic or Skylake, currently, Intel Skylake or later + your chosen GPU type NVDIA Tesla K80 is not a supported combination.  It is recommended that you should try other combinations like other CPU platform with GPU type or Skylake and P100 or other.

Comment: Yeah, that's what a guy from Google support eventually told me. It's pity their system can't notify during config stage.I wasted so much time with this issue.